# Get parameters from URL after # tag

Tags: javascript

How can I get Parameter values from url after # tag? for example, I have the url like this

```
1) index.html#page=home
2) index.html#page=topic?secid=1&catid=1
```

from above urls, i have to get parameter values of page, secid and catid.

Comment: Parse your `window.location.hash`.

Comment: there is no standard encoding for such "params", but it looks like a plain queryString decoder should work

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev `location.hash` is inconsistent across browsers. Better to parse `location.href`.

Comment: for all, i can able to get values after # tag like this "page=topic?secid=1&catid=1". After that i dont know i have to split.

Comment: @CMraj After that use regex, `var params = str.match(/page=([a-z]+)\?secid=(\d+)&catid=(\d+)/); var page = params[1], secId = params[2], catId = params[3];`

Comment: i think OP wants a parser, not a slicer...

Answer (score 2):

To get all of the text, you can use `window.location.hash`, including the hash symbol.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) some information about parsing query string parameters.

Comment: `location.hash` is inconsistent across browsers. Better to parse `location.href`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: what browsers have trouble with location.hash? i've used it a lot without issues...

Comment: If memory serves and nothing has changes recently, Mozilla browsers will automatically decode entities, but other browsers will not, leaving you with a string that may or may not be decoded. I'm not sure if there is a spec that defines the behavior one way or the other. Old IE also had trouble, especially IE6, but I don't remember all the details of that.